# Talkback should say label name first and then editbox when click on EditText

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, talkback

Is there any way that when the user clicks on the input type text field, it should speak label name first and then edit text? I have tried aria-label and aria-labelledby but both says label name after editbox.

**Here is an example:**

```
<label for="edittext" id="label" class="translatable input-label">Name</label>
<input type="text" class="translatable-pholder field-marker" aria-label="label" placeholder="Please fill" name="edittextfield" id="edittext"/ >
```

**Current Behavior:**
when clicking on the input field it says edit text, Name (label text), please fill, double-tap, etc

**Expected behavior:**
when clicking on the input field it should say Name, edit text, please fill, double-tap to ... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to force how a screen reader should announce things.  Just make sure your code is semantically correct and then let Talkback, VoiceOver, JAWS, and NVDA decide whether the role of the element (editbox) should be announced before or after the label.

A talkback user will be used to the way it announces things so if you change it, it'll be confusing.

Your code is good.  You have a `<label>` with the `for` attribute and it points to the `<input>`.